# Excel is recognizing duplicates in my .csv but not in R

Tags: r, excel, csv, duplicates

I am using the script

```
 df<-df %>% 
 group_by_all() %>% 
 filter(n()>1)
```

and since there are 160 columns in the df i am also using this script

```
df <- unique( df[ , 1:160 ] )
```

When i run these scripts it shows there are no duplicates so row numbers remain the same however when i open the export file in excel it recognizes the duplicates in their remove duplicate function. Don't understand why that is, is the dataframe being read differently?

Comment: I think without knowing your data `df` it's hard to come up with a useful answer. Bear in mind that Excel sometimes does conversions itself while opening a file. Also the accuracy in handling / displaying numbers will be different in R and Excel.

Comment: so i just attempted to trim as in all leading and trailing white spaces. I thought that would work but no. are there at least options you know or a source that i can look and try to play around with? I would send you the dataset but its 160 columns and for me its hard to look and see where the issue arises.

Comment: I tried with some random data myself but could not reproduce your problem. Like said, without knowing your data it is hard to explore this problem. Eventually Excel changes date formats, truncates number formats or adds additional columns because of the csv separator? All guessing right now.